# Unusual spacing in the description text of careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

[alt text http://cznp.com/images/careers_ow.png](http://cznp.com/images/careers_ow.png)

Comment: Which one's the unusual spacing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as needs details or clarity since it consists entirely of a dead image, which doesn't seem to have an archived copy available.

Comment: The link is broken (times out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element was incorrectly marked `clear:both`. It should have been `clear:left`.

Comment: I still see it.

Comment: ctrl+f5, because we cache static content for an hour.

Comment: Ah, ok.  All good.