# Unusual spacing in the description text of careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Unusual spacing in the description text of careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24968/unusual-spacing-in-the-description-text-of-careers)

[This is happening again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24968/unusual-spacing-in-the-description-text-of-careers). The URL for the spacing issue is here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/view

The image is an old one, but the issue looks the same.

[alt text http://cznp.com/images/careers_ow.png](http://cznp.com/images/careers_ow.png)

Answer (score 1):

This was introduced when we started converting the "Personal Statement" to Markdown, which wraps blocks of text in `<p>`.

Fixed in the next deployment.